# Error handling in SpringBoot kafka in Batch mode

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to figure out is there any way to send failed records in Dead Letter topic in Spring Boot Kafka in Batch mode.
I don't want to make the records being sent in duplicate as it's consuming in batch and few are already processed.
I saw this link of[spring-kafka consumer batch error handling with spring boot version 2.3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004225/spring-kafka-consumer-batch-error-handling-with-spring-boot-version-2-3-7)

I thought about a use case to stop container and start again without using DLT but again the issue of duplication will come in Batch mode.

@Garry Russel can you please provide a small code for batch error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RetryingBatchErrorHandler` was added in spring-kafka version 2.5 (which comes with Boot 2.3).

The listener must throw an exception to indicate which record in the batch failed (either the complete record, or the index in the list).

Offsets for the records before the failed one are committed and the failed record can be retried and/or sent to the dead letter topic.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#recovering-batch-eh

There is a small example there.

The `RetryingBatchErrorHandler` was added in 2.3.7, but it sends the entire batch to the dead letter topic, which is typically not what you want (hence we added the `RetryingBatchErrorHandler`).

Comment: Thanks Gary i am able to understand now completely. Though i am still stuck how to configure this properly in code:((

Comment: .Is this enough to set at config level factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new RecoveringBatchErrorHandler());

Comment: You can simply define the error handler as a `@Bean` and Spring Boot will automatically wire it into the auto configured factory. If you are defining your own factory then, yes just add it there. You most likely want to configure a recoverer though (such as the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`) and a `BackOff` into the error handler. The default one (like the one in your comment) is already wired in by the container. It will retry 9 times with no back off between attempts.

Comment: Thanks Gary it cleared my doubts completely:)).

Comment: I have asked a new question. It would be helpful if you can shed some light on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67992900/springboot-batch-listener-mode-vs-non-batch-listener-mode

Comment: @GaryRussell -> Have a question on the similar topic. Can you please help me to get some insights on this please [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396787/spring-kafka-exception-handling-with-manual-acknowledgment-mode]

Comment: @GaryRussell Can you please help to provide some insights on the below please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396787/spring-kafka-exception-handling-with-manual-acknowledgment-mode