# SpringBoot batch listener mode vs non-batch listener mode

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am just curious does batch listener mode in Spring Kafka gives better performance than non-batch listener mode?
If we are handling exceptions then we still need to process each record in Batch-listener mode. Non-batch seems less error prone, stable and customizable .

Please share your views on this as I didn't find any good comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It completely depends on what your listener is doing with the data.

If it processes each record in a loop then there is no benefit; you might as well just let the container iterate over the collection and send the listener one record at-a-time.

Batch mode will improve performance if you are processing the batch as a whole - e.g. a batch insert using JDBC in a single transaction.

This will often run much faster than storing one record at-a-time (using a new transaction for each record) because it requires fewer round trips to the DB server.

Comment: Yess that makes sense .In my case i was just trying to send the requests to different microservice.I tried using batch to make use of parallel stream apis but looks like its hard to manage failed offset as different threads can fail if service is down.

Comment: Given consumer takes some time to read the messages from Broker, which can vary from 1 ms to even 100 millis or more. would fetching messages in bulk i.e. reading 10 messages in 1 trip rather than reading 10 messages in 10 trip can make a difference ? in case if non-batch trip is taking 10 ms just to fetch each message, and if 200 messages are arriving every second ?

Comment: This seems to be an unrelated question - the number of messages fetched in a poll depends on various kafka properties (max.poll.records, min.fetch.bytes, etc, etc). This question is about how to process the records once they returned by the poll and has nothing to do with latency between client and broker. Yes, of course, it will be better to get more messages on each request. Don't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice.