# Spring-kafka exception handling with Manual Acknowledgment Mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

After a lot of effort and research on Kafka exception handling in Spring Boot application I am here for help.
I am using Spring boot version 2.5.9. Requirement is to handle the exceptions in spring kafka i.e., Retry the message for certain times and then commit the offset.

Firstly, I have tried with `seekToCurrentErrorHandler` with the Acknowledgment mode **Auto** as the below:

```
@Bean
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((r, e) ->  {
        log.info("in Error Handler record : {} and exception is : {}", r, e);
    }, new FixedBackOff(0L, 3L)); 
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    return factory;
}
```

And tested with an integrated test case, the Listener invoked 4 times and worked as expected.

```
verify(kafkaConsumer, times(4)).onMessage(isA(ConsumerRecord.class));
```

The same is invoking **only once** when provided Acknowledgment as **MANUAL or MANUAL_IMMEDIATE**

Secondly, have tried the below approach with RetryTemplate and Acknowledgment mode as **AUTO**

```
@Bean
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.setErrorHandler(((thrownException, data) -> {
        log.info("Exception in consumerConfig is {} and the record is {}", thrownException.getMessage(), data);
        //persist
    }));
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
    return factory;
}

private RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {

    FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(1000);
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(simpleRetryPolicy());
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
    return retryTemplate;
}


private RetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy() {

    SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(3);
    return simpleRetryPolicy;
}
```

this worked as expected, where the message retried processing with 3 attempts.

The same is invoking **only once** when provided Acknowledgment as **MANUAL or MANUAL_IMMEDIATE**

I unable to find any articles/docs/code repos on Kafka Exception Handling with **MANUAL** Ack Mode.
Kindly, Please suggest me some websites if any to handle the Spring kafka exceptions(Listener and Container level) with **MANUAL** Ack mode.

Comment: @GaryRussell - Can you please help me to find some docs or websites on this ?

Comment: This makes no sense to me; please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can see what's wrong.